# Cannot find function setValues in object Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

This error message is driving me crazy. It's probably so simple but I'm new to this. I appreciate any help I can get.

This program is for equipment inspections submitted through a google form by our employees. It should take the raw data from the submissions spreadsheet, check to see if there is a spreadsheet specific to the piece of equipment - if there is, it should make a new sheet with the date of the inspection, if there isn't, it should make a new spreadsheet with the title of the unit number of the equipment. I would then like the raw data to be copied to the new spreadsheet/sheet.

After this part is done I need to write code for formatting the raw data on the new sheet in to a more readable and user-friendly format - but I'm not quite there yet.

The issue is when I am trying to insert the heading values in to the new sheet (row 17) - "TypeError: Cannot find function setValues in object Spreadsheet. (line 17, file "Code")"

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    function onFormSubmit() {
  // onFormSubmit
  // get submitted data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1PieNQjjgjsZIEhTwmzGN9BcUXPSscWnWnnYL8XvjpTA");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Submissions");
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var Col = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var headings = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,Col).getValues();
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, Col);
  var UnitNumber = sheet.getRange(row,3,Col).getValue(); 
  // check if username has sheet
  if(ss.getSheetByName(UnitNumber)){
    var DrillSheet = ss.getSheetByName(UnitNumber);
    // if not make
  } else {
   var DrillSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(UnitNumber); 
    DrillSheet.getRange(1,1,1,Col).setValues(headings);
  }
  // copy submitted data to Drill sheet
  DrillSheet.appendRow(lastRow.getValues()[0]);
  DrillSheet.appendRow(['=CONCATENATE(B6," ",B5)']);
  DrillSheet.appendRow(['=TRANSPOSE(B1:2)']);
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Consider adding the error message, so your case can be understood more easily.

Comment: Thanks, error message added.

Comment: `Range` vs `Sheet` vs `Spreadsheet` - they are different classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the new spreadsheet, you need to define which individual sheet you want the headings to be added to. You need to get the sheet object with `.getSheetByName()`. The first sheet is always called "Sheet1", so you can get it by name in the script. A simple fix would be to change line 17 to:

```js
DrillSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1')getRange(1,1,1,Col).setValues(headings);
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple. I really appreciate it!

Comment: BTW Brian, I think you were on to something yesterday. This is working so great now, but it is still producing a new sheet every time, even when a spreadsheet for the unit number already exists.. Do you have an idea what is causing this?

Comment: Add `.toString()` on line 10 because getting the sheet by name is a string, not an object value.

Comment: I did that with no change. It was considering it a string before as well.

Comment: I think I found it. On line 10, you get `UnitNumber` as a range. It should be a cell if you want to compare it as a string. So, it should be: `var UnitNumber = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();` to get the last row, column 3. Otherwise, in your `if` block, you need to specify which index of the `UnitNumber` array you want to compare.